# Launching MS Word from Internet Explorer with parameters

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, ms-word

I have a requirement for within an ASP.Net application to open a Word template from within the browser and pass in some parameters to a MS Word plugin that will be installed on the client.

Is it possible when opening Word from the browser to pass in any parameters and if so how do you go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot launch an application from the browser. You can cause an application to run by downloading a document for which the application is the startup application. I do not believe you can supply parameters in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DSOFile to edit word document properties on the server very efficiently and the client-side plugin can read the parameters using the word object model.  This applies to *.doc files.  I'm not sure what the exact equivalent is with *.docx.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224351